# How to Condense BoxLayout in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, boxlayout

I'm using a vertical BoxLayout for a panel that is nested in some other panels. The size of the other panels causes the objects in my target panel to spread out in an unsightly manner. How do I make the panel present the objects from top to bottom without so much padding?

[image]

The following is similar code, although it produces spinners that fill the entire panel instead of normal looking spinners placed very far apart.

```
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JSpinner;
 import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

 public class PanelTest {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JPanel spinPanel1 = new JPanel();
    spinPanel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(spinPanel1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    spinPanel1.add(new JLabel("top"));
    SpinnerNumberModel spinMod1 = new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,10,1);
    spinPanel1.add(new JSpinner(spinMod1));
    leftPanel.add(spinPanel1);

    JPanel spinPanel2 = new JPanel();
    spinPanel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(spinPanel2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    spinPanel2.add(new JLabel("bottom"));
    SpinnerNumberModel spinMod2 = new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,10,1);
    spinPanel2.add(new JSpinner(spinMod2));
    leftPanel.add(spinPanel2);

    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
    rightPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));

    mainPanel.add(leftPanel);
    mainPanel.add(rightPanel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the code. We can't help if we don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Is that necessary for such a trivial problem? I thought there would be a simple solution like, boxLayout.condense();, or boxLayout.setPadding(0);

Comment: *"Is that necessary for such a trivial problem?"* **Yes.** Or rather, code that allows us to easily compile it and see the problem encourages people to help. If you could not be bothered posting such code, why should we bother trying to help?  Tip: Add @sorifiend (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @sorifiend I've included similar code, although it differs in that it creates spinners that extend over the entire panel rather than normal looking spinners that are spaced far apart. The code I posted still spaces the spinners far apart, so solving that should solve my problem.

Comment: @user2303321 I don't understand your problem. The code you added to your question shows two JSpinners that are evenly spaced and with no padding. So what is your issue? If you don't want items to be spread so far apart then you need to add padding (Rigid area, or a filler, or other empty elements), or use a different layout manager. See here for some BoxLayout info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html If you want better help then you need to show your actual code, and properly explain your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, mostly involving adding the panel with a (constraint /) layout that will honor the preferred size. In this case we use a `GridBagLayout` with default constraints. The component (`leftPanel`) added to it, is centered within the available space.

[image]

Each panel has a colored border to make its extent more obvious. This is a handy visual technique to use when debugging 'layout compaction'problems.

As an aside, I think the `leftPanel` looks crowded, and the non aligned spinners further detract from the appearance. I'd probably use a `GridBagLayout` for the labels and text fields (all in a single panel) with some padding & the labels right aligned.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class PanelTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // any single component added to this will be centered & have
        // its preferred size honored.
        JPanel constrainSpinnerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        constrainSpinnerPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.CYAN, 4));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED,4));
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE,4));
        leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel spinPanel1 = new JPanel();
        spinPanel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(spinPanel1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        spinPanel1.add(new JLabel("top"));
        SpinnerNumberModel spinMod1 = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 10, 1);
        spinPanel1.add(new JSpinner(spinMod1));
        leftPanel.add(spinPanel1);

        JPanel spinPanel2 = new JPanel();
        spinPanel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(spinPanel2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        spinPanel2.add(new JLabel("bottom"));
        SpinnerNumberModel spinMod2 = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 10, 1);
        spinPanel2.add(new JSpinner(spinMod2));
        leftPanel.add(spinPanel2);

        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GREEN, 4));
        rightPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));

        constrainSpinnerPanel.add(leftPanel);
        mainPanel.add(constrainSpinnerPanel);
        //mainPanel.add(leftPanel);
        mainPanel.add(rightPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```